# Is there a way to get the config of the account and roles, warehouses using snowpark api

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

Is there a way to extract the config of the account,roles and warehouses from snowflake api. Is it possible to use the api to create ones using the extracted config?

```
from snowflake.snowpark import Session

from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udf, col, month, sql_expr
from snowflake.snowpark import functions as F
from snowflake.snowpark.types import StringType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField, ArrayType
from snowflake.snowpark import DataFrame
import os
connection_parameters = {
    "account": os.environ["SNOW_ACCOUNT"],
    "user": os.environ["SNOW_USER"],
    "password": os.environ["SNOW_PASSWORD"],
    "role": os.environ["SNOW_ROLE"],
    "warehouse": os.environ["SNOW_WAREHOUSE"],
    "database": os.environ["SNOW_DATABASE"],
    "schema": os.environ.get("SNOW_SCHEMA")
}
session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
```

Comment: Are you referring to get the data from [Information Schema](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html)? It looks to me the information you want can be retrieved from information schema and that is not Snowpark related but can be retrieved using Snowpark.

Comment: Data like show users,show warehouses and maybe information schema too. I see the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views provides a SQL interface to the same information provided by the SHOW <objects> commands. 

 I know how to do it via console but is it possible this can be retrieved using snowpark and how?

Comment: Can we create a user via the snowpark api?

Answer (score 2):

Snowpark allows to execute any arbitrary SQL, for instance querying [ACCOUNT_USAGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html) schema:

```
df_sql = session.sql("SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.USERS")
df_sql.show()
```

Getting current session setup:

```
SELECT CURRENT_ACCOUNT(), CURRENT_USER(), CURRENT_ROLE(), ...
```

> *Can we create a user via the snowpark api?*

Yes, any query could be issued:

```
session.sql("CREATE USER <user_name> ").collect()
```

The crucial component are proper permissions to perform specific action, full list could be found at: [Access Control Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html)